# python file.write() not consistent output format

Tags: python-2.7, serialization, arduino, serial-port

I have been working on a project using an arduino (NANO ATmega328), that reads values from a heart rate + other sensors and sends the data in packets using serial communication. I then read the serial from a basic python script to write the data as a file to plot later.

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
final_output_file = open('final_output_file.out','w')

     while True: 
          initial =time.time()

          x = ser.readline() # Read the newest output from the Arduino

          final_output_file.write(str(initial)+" , " + str(x) )

          sleep(.01)
```

I am new to serial communication, and no doubt I am missing things (like exception handling) in this code, but it has done the job in the past providing data writing for long periods.

The issue I am having now is that sometimes the file is written as a binary(application/octet-stream) type and others it is a plain text output (what I want to plot from). Here is an example of one line of the differing outputs (if its useful):

binary(application/octet-stream) - One line of output

```
2c20 3020 2c20 3238 362e 3531 202c 2030
```

Plain text (what I want) - output

```
1451781797.29 , 0 , 518 , 147 , 0.00 , 0 , 0 , 0.00000000 , 0.00000000
```

I can see that they contain different number of entries. I have also tried converting back to strings from this (I know this might be moronic to, but in my naivety I did...).

I have tried looking at other questions to find answers. I use this site all the time and usually find what I want (this is my first post).

Is the arduino changing its output format randomly? I have printed the arduino output to the terminal to check, it doesn't seem to. My method for serial comm using the arduino is just:

Arduino serial print

```
Serial.print(Signal1);
Serial.print(" , ");
Serial.print(Signal2); 
...
```

As a hazard of a guess, `x = ser.readline()` in my python code (shown top) could be the culprit? Do I have to provide details of what data type I want to read? I would have thought that this would be implied though.

Please Help! If this is a rookie mistake....it's because I am a rookie! Happy to provide any further info if it'll be useful.

Arduino code:

```
    void loop(){
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH); //MUSIC SHIELD PULL HIGH TO NOT ACTIVATE

       if (i>count) //RESET AFTER 600 reads
        {
          i=0;
        }  

    Serial.print(i);                
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.print(Signal);                
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.print(BPM);                
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.print(gyro1); 
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.print('0');
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.print('0');
    Serial.print(" , ");
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers

  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)     
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)

 gyro_read1=gyro1;
 gyro1=sqrt(pow(GyX,2)+pow(GyY,2)+pow(GyZ,2));
 gyro_read2=gyro1;
 //Serial.println(digitalRead(11)); - Test push buttons
 int val=digitalRead(11);
 if(val==0)
 {
  sfx.playTrack(n0); 
 }

      if ( i == count) //if i reaches the 600 count mark, meaure the new unbiased std deviation
      { 
        stddev_heart_stat= myStats_heart.unbiased_stdev();
        stddev_gyro_stat=myStats_gyro.unbiased_stdev();


        Serial.print(stddev_heart_stat,8);
        Serial.print(" , ");
        Serial.println(stddev_gyro_stat,8);

        myStats_heart.clear();
        myStats_gyro.clear();

   if(stddev_gyro_stat<16.7 && stddev_heart_stat>5 && hour()>3 )
 //test   if(stddev_gyro_stat<18.7 && stddev_heart_stat>0 && hour()>0 )
        {
          uint8_t n = 0;
          sfx.playTrack(n);
          delay(3000);
            Serial.print(i);                
            Serial.print(" , ");
            Serial.print(0);                
            Serial.print(" , ");
            Serial.print(0);                
            Serial.print(" , ");
            Serial.print(0); 
            Serial.print(" , ");
            Serial.print('0');
            Serial.print(" , ");
            Serial.print('0');
            Serial.print(" , ");
            Serial.print(0);
            Serial.print(" , ");
            Serial.println(0);
          digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
        }
      }
      else
       {
           myStats_gyro.add(gyro1);
           myStats_heart.add(BPM);
           Serial.print(stddev_heart_stat,8);
           Serial.print(" , ");
           Serial.println(stddev_gyro_stat,8);
       } 

  heart_read1=BPM;
  heart_read2=BPM;
  delay(100); 
  i+=1; 
}
```

Comment: Do you use end of line characters when outputting from the arduino?

Comment: I use - Serial.println(); for the last signal read, so that it prints onto the next line, but no end of line character as such.